# RCA Rudin Definition 3.16 ,about $C_c(X)$ and $C_0(X)$

Tags: real-analysis

From the definition,it is clear that $C_c(X)$ is a subset of $C_0(X)$. Rudin says that if $X$ is compact,then $C_c(X)=C_0(X)$; how do we get that?

Comment: Every function on a compact space has compact support.

Comment: Thank you! I understand.

Comment: Another question :I used Page 36 Corollary "If A belongs to B....."to prove that Cc(X) is belongs to C0(X), I wonder is it the right way? Do you have an easier way to prove that?